# jquery ui tabs blind effect not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to get the effects to work with jquery ui version 1.10.2 
My html page is shown below. The tabs work but the blind effect doesn't happen.
What am I doing wrong?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Tabs</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="myTabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#a">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#b">Tab 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="a">This is the content panel linked to the first tab, it is shown by default.</div>
    <div id="b">This is the content panel linked to the second tab, it is shown when its tab is clicked.</div>  
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="development-bundle/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.tabs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($) {
        var tabOpts = {
            hide: {
                effect: "blind",
                duration: 2000
            },
            show: {
                effect: "blind",
                duration: 2000
            }

        };
        $("#myTabs").tabs(tabOpts);
    })(jQuery);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your exact same code worked fine for me in Chrome. [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uVQDV/)  Is it a particular browser giving you issues?

Comment: Thank you Miguel for your reply I saw your fiddle. The above html document will not work correctly in either the chrome browser or firefox. On thing I did find though that if I replaced the 4 script elements that call the development-bundle with calls to Google Hosted Libaries as follows:  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script> and <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> It works fine. It seems something is wrong with the calls to the development bundle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because you are including a partial jQuery UI version.

In jQuery UI tabs to let the show/hide with effect `blind` works you have to include the jQuery UI `effects` component http://api.jqueryui.com/category/effects/

See the page http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/ and read the section **Dependencies**

> UI Core
>   Widget Factory
>   Effects Core (optional; for use with the show and hide options)

If you include the entire jQuery UI, as in the last comment, it works because it contains all the libraries.